# codecs issue when writing to csv python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
output_file = open(OUTPUT_FILENAME,'w',newline='') #create new file
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
dict_writer.writeheader()
#some logic
for row in items:
    #di dictionary
    dict_writer.writerow(di)
```

Hello, I am new to python. I created this script on Linux (centos) I ran it and it works fine,
I tried running it on windows I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user157\Desktop\test.py", line 180, in <module>
    dict_writer.writerow(di)
  File "C:\Users\user157\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\user157\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1256.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 33: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried solving it by using before I write the dictionary but still same error

```
for k,v in di.items():
    try:
        di[k] =v.encode().decode('utf-8')
    except:
        pass
```

I have python 3.7.5 on centos and 3.8.2 on windows

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what your input file encoding is in Windows and use encoding='' in your input file open statement. In windows the default ending is not 'utf8' and therefore will have encoding issues if not opened with correct encoding like below,

```
open(input_file_name,encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

or better change your input file to 'utf8' encoding, so that the script can be used without modification on windoes and in linux.